# Reference two different values to retrieve number

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table that looks like this the 1260 is linked to the numbers beside them which represent individual accounts that all combine in 1260.

[image]

And another table that lists the linked accounts with dollar amounts beside them like this:

```
1210-110|$400
1220-110|$300
1310-120|$500
1650-110|$200
```

As of now in a third table I have to manual look and find the linked dollar amount and add up the totals of the second table linked amounts so the total for 1260 is the 400+300+200=$900 but they are all split up into the linked accounts(1210-110,1220-110,1650-110) and there is a lot of data.

Is there a formula I can use to retrieve and add up the dollar amounts in the second table using the 1260 in the first table as a reference to  the dollar amounts? I thought I would use an IF formula but I don't know how to retrieve the dollar amounts.

Answer (score 1):

use SUMIFS in a SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(E2:E5,D2:D5,B2:B7)*(A2:A7=H2))
```

[image]

---

If one has the dynamic array formula in office 365 then

```
=SUM(XLOOKUP(FILTER(B2:B7,A2:A7=H2),D2:D5,E2:E5,0,0))
```

Which may be a little quicker in large datasets.